# No muestra registros con campos NULL (CONSULTAS)

Tags: php, php5, nullpointerexception

Buenas noches realizo un formulario que funciona como una bitácora de equipos de computo, en mi BD tengo campos nulos (no tengo problema alguno con la inserción).

El problema que tengo es que en `mi modulo de consultas` **no me aparecen esos registros si hay campos null y necesito que me muestre en mi formulario sin importar si hay o no campos null** ya que necesito visualizar todos los registros que se han almacenado, quiero pensar que es por el Inner Join (ya que tengo campos en tablas foráneas) ya que antes de ponerlo si visualizaba todos los registros.

Gracias

Estructura de mi tabla

```
id_prestamo         PK  
fecha1  
hora1   
descripcion
id_usuario          FK
id_departamento     FK
id_entrega          FK
fecha2                  NULL
hora2                   NULL
id_ingeniero        FK  NULL
id_recepcion        FK  NULL
```

**Codigo de Modulo de Consultas**

```html
<?php

       require("connect_db.php");
    //$sql=("SELECT * FROM prestamo order by id_prestamo");
    
    
    $sql=("SELECT ps.id_prestamo, ps.fecha1, ps.hora1, ps.descripcion, usr.nombre, dep.descripcion, ent.descripcion, ps.fecha2, ps.hora2, ing.descripcion, rcp.descripcion
    FROM prestamo ps
    INNER JOIN usuarios usr  ON usr.id_usuario = ps.id_usuario
    INNER JOIN departamento dep ON dep.id_departamento = ps.id_departamento
    INNER JOIN entrega ent ON ent.id_entrega = ps.id_entrega
    INNER JOIN ingeniero ing ON ing.id_ingeniero = ps.id_ingeniero
    INNER JOIN recepcion rcp ON rcp.id_recepcion = ps.id_recepcion order by id_prestamo");
    
    
 
//la variable  $mysqli viene de connect_db que lo traigo con el require("connect_db.php");
    $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

    echo "<table border='2'; class='table table-hover';>";
     echo "<tr class='warning'>";
        echo "<td>ID del Equipo</td>";
      echo "<td>Fecha  de  Inicio</td>";
      echo "<td>Hora Inicio</td>";
      echo "<td>Descripción</td>";
      echo "<td>Usuario</td>";
      echo "<td>Departamento</td>";
      echo "<td>Estatus Entrega</td>";
      echo "<td>Fecha de Entrega</td>";
      echo "<td>Hora Fin</td>";
      echo "<td>Ingeniero</td>";
      echo "<td>Estatus Recepción</td>";
      echo "<td>Editar </td>";
      
     echo "</tr>";

       
   ?>
     
   <?php 
     while($arreglo=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
       echo "<tr class='success'>";
         echo "<td>$arreglo[0]</td>";
         echo "<td>$arreglo[1]</td>";
         echo "<td>$arreglo[2]</td>";
         echo "<td>$arreglo[3]</td>";
         echo "<td>$arreglo[4]</td>";
      echo "<td>$arreglo[5]</td>";
      echo "<td>$arreglo[6]</td>";
      echo "<td>$arreglo[7]</td>";
      echo "<td>$arreglo[8]</td>";
      echo "<td>$arreglo[9]</td>";
      echo "<td>$arreglo[10]</td>";
      

         echo "<td><a href='actualizar_prestamo.php?id_prestamo=$arreglo[0]'><img src='images/actualizar.gif' class='img-rounded'></td>";
      
      

      
     echo "</tr>";
    }


   ?>
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` es tu amigo

Comment: @JDev te dio la solución, puedes echarle un vistazo a los diferentes Join aqui: https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join

Comment: @JDev Muchas gracias, por tu aporte es lo que necesitaba. Saludos